# xpath to pull nodes based on element partial match

Tags: xpath

On the below xml snip i'd like to pull row nodes for different batches which is essentially a time stamp, i.e., `JP1800` stands for Japan 18 o'clock time.

`//*[Batch='LN12000']` pulls all London noon nodes while
`data/row` pulls all of them including empty `Batch` values.

How would I pull all London times as  `//*[Batch='LN'*]` does not work?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<data>
+<header>
+<row>
+<row>
+<row>
-<row>
    <Date>2019-10-21</Date>
    <Series>23</Series>
    <OnTheRun>N</OnTheRun>
    <Depth>0</Depth>
    <Batch>JP1700</Batch>
 </row>
-<row>
    <Date>2019-10-21</Date>
    <Series>23</Series>
    <OnTheRun>N</OnTheRun>
    <Depth>4</Depth>
    <Batch>JP1800</Batch>
</row>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like `starts-with` function. :

`//header/row/Batch[starts-with(.,"LN")]`

And here we have some PHP code exemple, look:

```php
    <?php
    $xml = <<<XML
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <data>
        <header>
            <row>
                <Date>2019-10-21</Date>
                <Series>23</Series>
                <OnTheRun>N</OnTheRun>
                <Depth>0</Depth>
                <Batch>JP1700</Batch>
            </row>
            <row>
                <Date>2019-02-05</Date>
                <Series>27</Series>
                <OnTheRun>X</OnTheRun>
                <Depth>89</Depth>
                <Batch>LN9877</Batch>
            </row>
        </header>
    </data>
    XML;
    
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $query = $xpath->query('//header/row/Batch[starts-with(.,"LN")]');
    
    /** @var DOMElement $node */
    foreach ($query as $node) {
        print($node->nodeValue); //outputs LN9877
    }
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with